# What is the difference between `poetry lock` and `poetry update --lock`?

Tags: python, python-poetry

What is the difference between `poetry update --lock` and `poetry lock`? I wasn't able to find much useful hints in the official docs and I know that both are not the same since we recently had to switch from `poetry update --lock` to `poetry lock` for upgrading packages because of unexpected issues.

Comment: Then there must be an issue with installing the packages using Poetry.

Answer (score 23):

Summary: you're not updating packages in `poetry.lock` file anymore.

---

[`poetry lock`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#lock) creates a `poetry.lock` file, but does not install packages.

(`poetry lock --help` description):

> The lock command reads the pyproject.toml file from the current directory, processes it, and locks the dependencies in the poetry.lock file.

"Processing" means resolving dependencies to be compatible, (by default, with latest versions). **`poetry lock` does NOT install packages, it just generates a `poetry.lock` file.**

Let's say I have package A and it has sub-dependency B.

1. `poetry lock` resolves all dependencies and their sub-dependencies in the `pyproject.toml` file.
2. By default, it will try to update all the sub-dependency versions. So it'll try to update the latest version of A and the latest version of B.
3. `--no-update` will prevent any updates. Instead, Poetry will focus on making the `pyproject.toml` versions compatible, but will use whatever versions are compatible with the currently existing versions in the `pyproject.toml`. That means even though Package A is compatible with the latest version of package B, it will not update package B, it will just make sure that some compatible package B is used.

---

[`poetry update`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#update) also updates the package versions and then installs the updates.

1. Resolves dependencies to be compatible with each other, just like `poetry lock`
2. Creates or updates `poetry.lock` like `poetry lock`
3. **Installs** the packages, which is different. The documentation doesn't explicitly mention this, but you can infer from the description for `--lock` flag, which does not perform an install, but just updates `poetry.lock`

From the documentation linked above:

> --lock : Do not perform install (only **update** the lockfile).

Notice that updating not only installs a new package, but also **updates** several packages.

```
$ poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (106.7s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 1 install, 39 updates, 0 removals
```

---

Wait, but that basically just sounds like `poetry install`!

Almost. [`poetry install`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install) lazily installs, i.e.:

- If a `poetry.lock` exists, it just installs the packages specified by the lock file.
- If no `poetry.lock` exists, it acts like `poetry update` and tries to resolve dependencies in `pyproject.toml`, create a `poetry.lock`, and then installs them.

Thus, `poetry install` is the same as `poetry update` if there's no `poetry.lock` file. It's only slightly more convenient to install directly from the `poetry.lock` file if you don't want to update dependencies.

---

My experience has been: just use `poetry update` unless you have a very specific circumstance. In your case, there was probably some package that couldn't be updated because that version was explicitly being used, and upgrading would cause something to break in a hard-to-fix way.

Comment: That `TLDR` of yours is very confusing to me

Comment: TLDR stands for "Too Long; Didn't Read" which is a way of saying "here's a summary", but because this is uncommon to many folks, I've edited it out of my post.

Comment: The problem was definitely not literally `TLDR`. It is the actual "summary". My comment was made a while ago but looking at your "summary" again, it doesn't summarize your actual answer and just leaves me more confused as to what you meant by it.

Comment: I felt that it properly summarized the issue, but I'm happy to see that you provided an alternatively worded explanation that seems more concise. I hope that others who were confused by mine can refer to yours.

Answer (score 4):

When called with no other arguments, **they do the same thing.**

If you check the source code, you will see they both end up calling the same function ([`def run`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/1.6/src/poetry/installation/installer.py#L92)) for updating the lock file. Prior to that, they both call [`def execute_operations`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/1.6/src/poetry/installation/installer.py#L159) with argument `False` to avoid actually installing anything.

#### The Difference

The only thing that is different is what other options you can pass while calling those commands. Those can affect what you're trying to do. You can see these extra options in the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/).

- `poetry lock`: `--no-update` ([source code](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/1.6/src/poetry/console/commands/lock.py))
- `poetry update --lock`: `packages --without --with --only --dry-run` ([source code](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/1.6/src/poetry/console/commands/update.py))

##### Examples

So, for example, you could create/update the lock file without updating any packages previously pinned in `pyproject.toml` or updating any pinned version in `poetry.lock` to its latest version **only** by using the following command:

```
poetry lock --no-update
```

Similarly, you could update a specific package version just in the lock file **only** by using the following command:

```
poetry update [package] --lock
```

Or you could test a lock file update by running it in `dry-run` mode **only** by using the following command:

```
poetry update --lock --dry-run
```

You might also think you could update just the lock file's dev dependencies by using the following command:

```
poetry update --lock --only=dev
```

but as of 1.6, that just doesn't work for whatever reason.